# Run socket.io from an express route

Tags: express, mongoose, websocket, socket.io

I have researched on this but nothing seems to satisfy my need. I have an express route connected to a mongodb. Below is part of the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const dbconnect = require("./models");
const handle = require("./handlers");
const routes = require("./routes");

const app = express();
app.use('/messages', routes.messages);

const PORT = 3000;

const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log(`Listening on 3000`);

  dbconnect().then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDb connected");
  });
});

const io = socketIo(server); 
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log('Connected...');
});
```

My route looks like this:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const handle = require('../handlers/messages');

router.post('/unread_messages', handle.unread_messages);

module.exports = router;
```

My handler looks like this:

```
const db = require("../models");

exports.unread_messages = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    
  const unreadmessages = await db.messages.countDocuments({ $and: [{receiver: req.body.receiver}, 
  { messageread: false }]});
      return res.json({ unreadmessages });
    
  } catch (err) {
     return next({ status: 400, message: `Cannot get unread messages ${err}` });
  }
};
```

I would like to add socket to the "/unread_messages" route so that I get an update of the count of unread messages in realtime. How do I do that?